# Add a Training section on CV

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv

I would like to make a request for training section on CV, as I think those of us who are lucky enough for an employer to pay for training or may have even paid for it themseleves would like to demonstrate they have invested in their careers

Comment: Is this general training or training where you recieve a certificate of completion/official paperwork?

Comment: The example I was thinking about was something along the lines of a jboss course, sure I can pick up what I need to know from reading blogs and forums etc, but I would expect someone who had been on a specifc course to know the right way to do something without having to spend hours hunting in the internet (or waiting for an answer on stackoverflow)

Comment: I've seen people "pass" C# and .Net training that had no idea that .Net and Java were different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Agreed!</strike> Might as well get some mileage out of those team-building exercises we got sent to...

EDIT: I strongly disagree with Stu that this is not a valuable metric of the candidate's skills. There are many kinds of training that are very relevant, such as Agile scrum-master certification, Toastmasters (public speaking), or managerial leadership training. Not to mention all the various certificates that Microsoft hands out!

If I were a 17 year old kid and went to a summer camp for Ruby, I'd definitely want to highlight that. It's going to set me head and shoulders above all the other I-have-no-degree-but-I'm-awesome-anyway sorts of candidates.

EDIT: I humbly withdraw my agreement. I'll leave up this post however so we don't lose the banter attached to it. It still might be still useful to put on the resume, but it doesn't need its own section.

Comment: Any project that 17-year-old kid did at 'Camp Ruby' is the valuable part, not the summer camp itself, where half the kids' fellow campers are absolutely useless...yet stick the *"I went to Camp Ruby, therefor I can code!"*.  I'd liken this to the difference between *"Doing It"* and *"Talking About Doing It"*.  That's the thing I am impressed with about CSO--it makes an effort to tie in actual work product with the job seeker, rather than 'poser product' like training certificates.

Comment: @Stu: so why not eliminate the "Education" section as well, since going to university is not as valuable as having done something there? ...Because the act of having attended is a symbol of probably having learned something. (Yes, I've met many dolts with degrees, which is why you still need to confirm in the interview that the education/training actually left an impression.)

Comment: Are you seriously equating a four-year Computer Science degree, with lots of exams to test knowledge, with a 3-day every-body-gets-a-sticker Scrum course? *Seriously?* I'm not saying anybody who has a degree from uni is great. But a BSCS is a once in a life time education achievement. **A training course is scholastic Pez.**

Comment: No, absolutely not. But I don't think it has zero value on my resume, especially if I have demonstrable experience using some buzzword technology that the prospective employer uses.

Comment: You are able put your training into your CSO profile *now*.  The question is, does CSO need a separate section to detail user's training history? *I say 'no'.*  To do so is merely distracting, useless creature-freap.  A cornify button would be more valuable.

Comment: Ok, you win! I took a look at my most recent resume (~1.5 years old) and discovered much to my chagrin that I had a single "Education and Training" section, where I lumped everything together: Dale Carnegie leadership, Agile blah blah, and University BSc all in one section. I'll concede that there's not much point in separating them out. I've edited my post above to reflect that.

Comment: We all win, Ether.  :)

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

Training is not a very good metric of your skills.

One of the things J&J seem to be addressing with CSO is the crap way Internet based job searches work.  The main thing they've got going with CSO is the tie in to SO.  What you are proposing diminishes from keeping CSO clean, functional and relevant to the quality of a job seeker.  I'd even suggest that any employer who thinks training matters is not the kind of employer that CSO is excited about having.

Comment: What? I feel that any training that I've had to do something is relevant. If my company brought in an expert and taught my team about some technique, principle, or paradigm, that should be highlighted.

Comment: I would say that it demeonstrates an interest in further developing yourself as a developer, someone who has sought to be taught more about a technology as oppsed to someone who has built up knowledge through experience. 

Anytime I have been on a course I have requested it myself, to improve my developemnt skills, which I think is one of key factors that J&J are interested in displaying with CSO is that developers listed on CSO are not just mortgage driven developers but live and breath development

Comment: A good programmer is engaged in On-The-Job training *on a regular basis.* Via blogs, books, discussions, conferences, etc. Do we need to formalize all of them into CSO fields too? **No.** This requests, to add a training section, only appeals to simpleton, bureaucratic instincts-- *"Programmer A is better than programmer B because he/she has 3 more training classes! Hire!"* I'm sure HR people love this idea. Quality coding shops? Not so much. Question for you: *Do you compare and contrast yourself with other coders based on what and how many training courses they have been too?*